# Why is removeClass not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make some effects to work but I can't. I have a list of divs and I want 4 buttons.

1) Load more

2) Show less

3) Change max

4) Change min

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhcxo66k/). I don't know why on JSFiddle the removeClass and addClass don't work because on my computer they work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#changeMax').on('click', function(){
        $('li.col-md-3').addClass('fullwidth');
    });
    $('#changeMin').on('click', function(){
        $('li.col-md-3').removeClass('fullwidth');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $(".row li").size();
    x=3;
    $('.row li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+4 : size_li;
        $('.row li:lt('+x+')').show("fast");
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 4 : x-4;
        $('.row li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide("fast");
    });
});
```

I will explain my problem from my computer. The first 3 buttons work with animation. The removeClass works but not with animation. I tried but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to add document.ready twice.

Comment: It is working. It's adding `.fullwidth` to your `<li>` elements.

Comment: Use length instead of size(). According to docs, size is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 1):

Because of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), other rules have a higher value

The rule `.row li.col-md-3{` has a greater value than `.fullwidth` so the new width will not apply.

Change

```
.fullwidth{
```

to

```
.row li.fullwidth{
```

and it will start to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just some css issues.

A quick fix is to use `!important`, but that is not always recommended.

```
.fullwidth{
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is showing that the fullwidth class is added:

```
$('#changeMax').on('click', function(){
        $('.row li.col-md-3').addClass('fullwidth');
        alert($('.row li.col-md-3')[0].className);
});
```